# Java: mapping/copying from source to destination having different member varialbles

Tags: java

I have two classes Person and Employee as below.

```
    Person{
    private String name;
    private String gender;
    private String address;
    }

    Employee{
    private String name;
    private String gender;
    }
```

I want to copy Person into Employee. Since both objects are not equal in structure, how to copy the objects?

Comment: You couldn't copy the objects, even if they were equal in structure.  That's what the concept of ***type safety*** is all about.

Comment: @4castle he would still not be able to copy the objects, at least not without writing code that copies fields one by one, and if he did that, it would work regardless of whether he was using inheritance.

Comment: @MikeNakis I'm not sure what you mean. You could just make a constructor that uses getters to copy in the values, and then sets `address` to null or an empty string.

Comment: @4castle I amended my comment.

Comment: @MikeNakis My recommendation to use inheritance was not an answer to copying fields. Copying fields one by one is exactly how this would be done. Or if `Employee` is the superclass, you could just use casting.

Comment: @4castle casting and copying are unrelated.  True, the OP might not know the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Give your classes accessor and mutator methods (also commonly called "Getters" and "Setters") for their private fields. E.G. for your Employee class:

```
Employee {
    private String name;
    private String gender;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return this.gender;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to specify the state of one object based on the values of the other. For example...

```
employee.setName(person.getName());
```

And there are multiple ways to skin this class. Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
Employee {
    private String name;
    private String gender;

    Employee(Person person) {
        this.name = person.getName();
        this.gender = person.getGender();
    }
}
```

(Note that you would lose your no-arg constructor if you did exactly this!)